# C# .NET image to Mysql upload

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am battling with an error that happens when I attempt to upload an image to DataBase.
This only happens after publishing.

I have already set the folder permissions.  I have been trying to get around this for few days now.  Can anyone help out.

Here is my code

```
string filePath = Path.GetFileName(oFile.PostedFile.FileName.ToString());
string uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/upload");
oFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(uploadPath,File.PostedFile.FileName));

string sql = "INSERT INTO `DataBase`.`table` 
           (image) 
           VALUES (@file)";

using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", 
            File.ReadAllBytes(uploadPath + "\\" + filePath));                    
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
connection.Close();
```

Here is the Error keep getting when the site is live.
This doesn't happen on localhost.
I have already followed the steps to grant access. I have read many answers regarding the access granting. I must be missing something.
Please help out.

```
Access to the path 'E:\www\website\website\wwwroot\upload\Image-01.jpg' is 
denied.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 
 'E:\www\website\website\wwwroot\upload\Image-01.jpg' 
 is denied. 

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider 
granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. 
ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or 
Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool 
identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. 
If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the 
identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the 
authenticated request user. 

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, 
choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the 
appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the 
boxes for the desired access.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web 
request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can 
be identified using the exception stack trace below.


Stack Trace: 
[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 
'E:\www\premileh\website\wwwroot\upload\Image-01.jpg' 
is denied.]
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +417
System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, 
Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, 
FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean 
bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) +1217
System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, 
FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, 
Boolean bFromProxy) +130
System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) +97
System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename) +96
application.ItemUploadPage.ImageUploader()in
C:\Users\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder.aspx.cs:133
app.apppage.UploadBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
\Users\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\app
\ItemUploadPage.aspx.cs:97
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11758848
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String 
eventArgument)+150
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean 
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5028

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET 
Version:4.7.3282.0`
```

Please guys. Your assistance will greatly appreciated.

Gareth

Comment: Please, please, please *DON'T* create SQL strings by concatenation. Since you already added `@file` as a parameter, why not add *all* other values as parameters?

Comment: As for `Access Denied`, this has nothing to do with MySQL or C#. Your web app's account has no permission to read that file.  The error message clearly explains that. You don't need that path though - [FileUpload.FileBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas?view=netframework-4.7.2) already provides the contents of the uploaded file. If you want to save the file first, use [FileUpload.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the feedback.  The SaveAs is already there.

Comment: Why do you build a *different* path then, instead of using the string you already created? BTW check the actual path. It's `E:\www\website\website`. Store `Path.Combine(uploadPath,File.PostedFile.FileName)` in the `filePath` instead and use it as is.

Comment: string filePath = Path.GetFileName(oFile.PostedFile.FileName.ToString());  Is the name of the image.  Image.jpg.                   string uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/upload");  Creates a path to where the image is \...\...\..upload\.      
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 oFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(uploadPath,File.PostedFile.FileName));   Combines the two    \...\...\...\upload\image.jpg             and saves it.       However.  I still get an access denied error.

Comment: I have given the permissions on the folder.  It works on localhost, however when i publish and test the website, it give me the access denied error.